# How to compare if a set of LocalDate (holidays) contains a given MonthDay?

Tags: java, localdate

How do i exctract the monthDay in a LocalDate?  I need to solve this within tomorrow so any help soon would be apreciated!

```
private final Set<MonthDay> recurringHolidays = new HashSet<>();
private final Set<LocalDate> holidays = new HashSet<>();


public void setHoliday(final LocalDate date) {
     holidays.add( date );
}

public void setHolidayIfIsRecurring() {

    for (LocalDate holidayLocalDate: getHolidays())
        for (MonthDay monthDay: getRecurringHolidays()){
            
            LocalDate monthdayToLocalDate = monthDay -------------????
            
            if (!setOfHolidays().contains( monthdayToLocalDate ) ){
                setHoliday( (monthDay) );
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: both. first i need to check if a set of LocalDates (holidays) contains a Monthday (recurringHolidays). If not, then I need to add a Monthday to a Localdate with this current year and use setHoliday() which receives that new localdate.

Comment: I know how to convert LocalDate to Monthday but not reversed

Comment: no i mean to just create a new LocalDate for the current year of today as in 2020 using Year.now() and add that Monthday to that new localdate and then use setHoliday(Localdate), which receives that newly created Localdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `LocalDate` → `MonthDay`

You can use [`MonthDay#from(TemporalAccessor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)). For example:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.MonthDay;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 20);
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.from(date);
    System.out.println(md);
  }
}
```

That will output:

```
--6-20
```

---

## `MonthDay` → `LocalDate`

The issue here is that `MonthDay` obviously only represents a *month* and *day-of-month*, whereas `LocalDate` additionally represents a *year*. You need to decide how to determine what year should be used. Once you know that then two options are:

- [`MonthDay#atYear(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#atYear(int)), or
- [`Year#atMonthDay(MonthDay)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#atMonthDay(java.time.MonthDay)).

For example:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.MonthDay;
import java.time.Year;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.of(6, 20);
    Year year = Year.of(2020);
    
    LocalDate date1 = md.atYear(year.getValue());
    LocalDate date2 = year.atMonthDay(md);

    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(date2);
  }
}
```

That will output:

```
2020-06-20
2020-06-20
```